# Настройка Nginx

Tags: php, nginx

Недавно начал изучать Nginx.
Делал настройку по этой ссылке http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/nginx-phpfpm

```
votan@votan-N53SN:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled$ cat example.com 
include common/upstream;
server
{
listen  80;
listen  443 ssl;
root            /var/www/html;
index           index.php index.html index.htm;
server_name     example.com www.example.com;
client_max_body_size        200m;
fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;
location "/"
{
index index.php index.html index.htm;   # варианты индексных файлов если имя файла в запросе не задано
try_files   $uri $uri/  =404;   # проверить есть ли файл из запроса на диске, иначе - вернуть ошибку 404
}
}
```

Сервер стартует но при переходе на example.com или localhost выходит данная страница [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По ссылке localhost/index.php - идет скачка файла index.php

Php-fpm   /etc/nginx/common/php-fpm

```
# Настройки порта или сокета PHP-FPM производятся в файле    "/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf"
fastcgi_pass    php-fpm;
# Порядок важен - строчка "include fastcgi_params" должна быть первой
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)?$;
# Вместо переменной "$document_root" можно указать адрес к корневому каталогу сервера и это желательно (см. http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls)
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME        $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   PATH_TRANSLATED     $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
# См. http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
set     $path_info      $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO       $path_info;
# Additional variables
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADMIN        email@example.com;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SIGNATURE    nginx/$nginx_version;
fastcgi_index   index.php;
```

Comment: Раз: вполне возможно, страница эакэшировалась, попробуйте Ctrl+Shift+R. Два: про php-fpm в конфиге ни строчки, php-код никто выполнять не будет, он и должен просто скачиваться. Три: комментарий к try_files не совсем правильный

Comment: У вас все еще в конфиге нет ничего про php...

Comment: добавил  /etc/nginx/common/php-fpm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в конфиг обработку пхп

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/)(/.*)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Comment: добавил в конец example.com - ничего не изменилось

Comment: это нужно вставить в секцию server { }, после чего у Вас будут работать пхп скрипты